# Upload image to s3 from url

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload a image, for which i have a url into s3

I want to do the same without downloading the image to local storage

```
filePath = imageURL;
          let params = {
            Bucket: 'bucketname',
            Body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
            Key: "folder/" + id + "originalImage"
          };
          s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            if (data) console.log("original image success");
          });
```

expecting a success but getting error : 
myURL is a https publicly accesible url.

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<myURL HERE>']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path:
   '<myURL HERE>' }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are attempting to do? Is the source image coming from Amazon S3, or simply a web-accessible URL? Or is it simply coming from the local disk? It is strange that you are setting a `filePath` to a web URL. Feel free to edit your question to clarify details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i have to upload 2 images into MY s3 bucket. one link is a web accesible cloudinary image link. and another is a web accesible amazon s3 link. both are https. 
I intend to make the upload happen without storing the same in a local directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to place files into an Amazon S3 bucket:

- **Upload** the contents via [`PutObject()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property), *or*
- **Copy** an object that is already in Amazon S3

So, in the case of your "web accessible Cloudinary image", it will need to be retrieved, then uploaded. You could either fully download the image and then upload it, or you could do some fancy stuff with streaming bodies where the source image is read into a buffer and then written to S3. Either way, the file will need to be "read" from Cloudinary the "written" to S3.

As for the "web accessible Amazon S3 link", you could use the [`CopyObject()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property) command to instruct S3 to directly copy the object from the source bucket to the destination bucket. (It also works *within* a bucket.)

Answer (score 1):

This will make a GET request to the image URL, and pipe the response directly to the S3 upload stream, without the need to save the image to the local file system.

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

const imageURL = 'https://example.com/image.jpg';
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const params = {
    Bucket: 'bucketname',
    Key: "folder/" + id + "originalImage"
};

const readStream = request(imageURL);
const uploadStream = s3.upload(params).createReadStream();

readStream.pipe(uploadStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following snippet to upload files in S3 using the file URL.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import awsSDK from 'aws-sdk';

const uploadImageToS3 = () => {
  const url = 'www.abc.com/img.jpg';
  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: url,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  })
 .then(function (response) {
   console.log('res', response.data);
   const arrayBuffer = response.data;
   if (arrayBuffer) {
     awsSDK.config.update({
       accessKeyId: 'aws_access_key_id',
       secretAccessKey: 'aws_secret_access_key',
       region: 'aws_region',
     });

    const s3Bucket = new awsSDK.S3({
      apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
      params: {
        Bucket: 'aws_bucket_name'
      }
    });

    const data = {
      Body: arrayBuffer,
      Key: 'unique_key.fileExtension',
      ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    const upload = s3Bucket.upload(data, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('s3 err:', err)
      }
      if (res) {
        console.log('s3 res:', res)
      }
    })
  }
});
}

uploadImageToS3();
```